# how to add Leiningen to .bashrc

Tags: bash, ubuntu, clojure, leiningen

I'd like to begin with clojure and I'm trying to install [Leiningen](http://leiningen.org/) (I'm running Ubuntu). I [downloaded the file](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen) and saved it to `~/Code/lein.sh` What's the proper way to add this to my `.bashrc` file? Does the name I chose (lein.sh) matter?

The end of my .bashrc looks like this:

```
### Added by the Heroku Toolbelt
export PATH="/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH"

### Java
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386

### Android
#~ export PATH=~/Code/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20131030/sdk/tools
#~ export PATH=~/Code/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20131030/sdk/platform-tools
export ANDROID_HOME=~/Code/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20131030/sdk/tools
export ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS=~/Code/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20131030/sdk/platform-tools
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME:$ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS:$PATH


[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
```

What's the proper way to add `~/Code/lein.sh` to my path using `.bashrc`?

Comment: Why you don't just put it under /usr/local/bin ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways.  The first, and recommended, way is not to change your `.bashrc` at all, but move `lein.sh` to a directory where your shell can find it when it's looking for executables.  `~/bin/` or `/usr/local/bin` are the most obvious candidates.  Type `echo $PATH` in your terminal to find out which directories are currently on your shells `PATH`.

If you insist on keeping lein.sh in its current location, you can extend the `PATH` list to include the `~/Code` directory.  Examples of extending `PATH` are already in the bits of `.bashrc` you quoted, just follow the pattern:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Code
```

This will make everything in `~/Code` a candidate for an executable, regardless of your current working directory.  It is not generally good practice.

Comment: Also, lein.sh should be renamed to lein